# Pause code execution in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know is there a way to stop code execution in jQuery until the function result is returned.

```
functionName() {
    //user inserts something
    return user_insertion;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    //code before
    if (var1.length > 1) result = functionName(data);
    else result = [data: 1, data: 2, data: 3];
    //code after, the one I want to pause execution of
    //do something with result that user inserted
});
```

Comment: *"I want to know is there a way to stop code execution in jQuery until the function result is returned."* **No.**

Comment: If you read those other questions, they should all say that you shouldn't do this.

Comment: Welcome to asynchronous programming.

Answer (score 0):

There is simply no `sleep` function in JavaScript because it does not support thread (except with the concepts of WebWorkers, but this is out of scope).

What you're looking for is probably the promise pattern. Take a look at the documentation here :
http://api.jquery.com/promise/

You should have your `functionName()` fullfilling a promise defined beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you :

```
functionName() {
    //user inserts something
    return user_insertion;
    callback();
}
function callback(){
  // do something after;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    //code before
    if (var1.length > 1) result = functionName(data);
    else result = [data: 1, data: 2, data: 3];
    //code after, the one I want to pause execution of
    //do something with result that user inserted
});
```

Comment: your return and execution of callback are out of order.